# How do I zip and unzip files in python?

Tags: python, file-transfer

I am trying to move a folder from one place to another, however I get this error when I try:
`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`

I use the following code:

```
import os.path, shutil #, zipfile
if os.path.exists("\\\BOGORODITSASERV\\Not.py Files"):
    print("#YOLO")
    #zip command
    shutil.copy2('C:\\Users\\Grant\\Documents\\AllDerProgramming','\\\BOGORODITSASERV\\Not.py Files')
    #unzip command
    print("Success!")
```

EDIT: I have made sure that the file is not open/being used. So to get around this error I was thinking zipping and unzipping the file would work.

EDIT:How then, if not by zipping, do I get rid if this error? Can I give python permission to this file path?

EDIT:I run this program on an admin account, I even run the shell as administrator and I still get the permission error.

Comment: You mention zip and unzip in your title, but never in your question, which is about copying a file. Which are you trying to do?

Comment: `Permission denied` says it all... the python process doesn't have access to one of the directories (depending on the line of the error)

Comment: How do I give python permission then?

Comment: You need permission to copy the file to the directory.  If the person calling python has permission, python has permission.  If you don't have permission, python won't have permission.